# How to show only methods and class-members?

Tags: netbeans, code-folding

I am trying to find out whether NetBeans v7.1 can fold everything in a Java class except:

- class name
- member names
- method names

So this simple class:

```
public class Example {
  private int someValue;
  public Example() {
    // Constructor logic
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    // method body
  }
}
```

Would fold into:

```
public class Example {
  private int someValue;
  public Example() { }
  public void doSomething() { }
}
```

Do you know any Java IDE that can do this? If so please let me know which one.

Comment: So your only problem are the empty lines that don't get collapsed?

Comment: Nope, my problem is that i do not want to manually fold *all* methods in my class. I want to collapse bodies of all methods, in other words...

Comment: Ahhh, it is not possible to print such folded source ... :'(

Comment: Well, thats another question :-) Just look at `File -> Print -> Print Options` and activate `Print as in Editor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

just type <kbd>ctrl + shift + -</kbd>

This should do the trick for you

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Navigator window and start typing the method name you seek. The method will be automatically selected in the Navigator tree, just then hitting  that Netbeans will position the cursor in the method definition in the code editor window.
If the Navigator window is not displayed you can turn in on using "Window -> Navigating -> Navigator" (or press Ctrl-7)